# Are New York pedestrians allowed to use bike lanes?

Tags: safety, legal, bike-lane

In NYC, some street bike lanes (specifically, one on 8th avenue in midtown) are typically full of walking pedestrians.

Is this legal? (e.g. are the pedestrians doing it actually jaywalking or violating some other law?)

If it is not legal, is there any evidence that NYC enforces this law in any way?

Comment: Related, but SanFran centric: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6190/are-runners-allowed-to-use-the-bike-lane

Comment: I think you'd have to ask the authorities in NYC.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - right. I can just imagine Mike Bloomberg cheerfully admitting in public "no, we don't really bother enforcing the law".

Comment: OK, then ask the folks in San Francisco.

Comment: Dunno if legal, but it is really dangerous!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the legality of walking in a bike lane and not about cycling. Outside of cycling advocacy activities, playing the blame game doesn't relate to riding a bike. 

Comment: Would asking if cars can park in the bike lane make a difference? The question seems to be about keeping the bike lane available for use by bikes.

Comment: @NeilFein - (1) Would you please explain what the off-topicality difference exists between this question and [this one](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6190/are-runners-allowed-to-use-the-bike-lane) - which you clearly know about and didn't complain of being off-topic (nor was it ever VTCed). (2) Avoiding being hit by a car because I'm swerving around pedestrians in a bike lane seems to be a reasonably important component of cycling, IMHO.

Comment: @DVK - Fair question. First off, I was a mod here at the time. Mods have to be more careful with their opinions, as their off-topic "votes" are binding. It's a completely different situation. But if my opinion irks you, take comfort in that nobody else seems to share it so far. (Tangentially - Looking back on this, I am now of the opinion that *both* questions are too localized, but the community here has voted to allow that.)

Comment: @RitchMelton - Yes, I'd agree that keeping the bike lane clear would make for a much better question.

Comment: @NeilFein - it wasn't the opinion, it was the seeming inconsistency :)  As far as keeping bike lane clear, I have so far been spared seeing any cars parked or driving in a bike lane. Pedestrians are the overwhelming hazard.

Comment: @NeilFein - as far as being localized - the SE definition is "unlikely to help anyone else", not "not applicable everywhere" - and NYC has a significant enough bike lane usage, as does SF, that IMHO both those questions can be helpful to others.

Comment: "How do I handle people walking in bike lanes?" might be a better question.

Comment: @Tom77 - that would seem to be a lot more opinion based than what I asked?

Answer (score 1):

If the lane you described is marked clearly for bicycle use, then I'd say the pedestrians are clearly in the wrong. There has to be numerous security cameras in the area that should catch these "jaywalkers" if the police ever have a reason to view security footage for some reason. I wonder how the "real" pedestrians on the sidewalk would feel if 5 or 6 dozen cyclists decided to trade the bike lane for the sidewalk for a day!? Bet that would cause a stir AND get the police department attention!

Comment: But keep in mind that in many circumstances pedestrians are permitted to walk on a roadway.  There should be no difference between a bikeway and a roadway, in this respect -- if the law allows the pedestrians to walk in the roadway it should permit them in an adjacent bikeway.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - Pedestrians are allowed to _cross_ roads, but they're not allowed to walk _in_ them.  I would expect the same would be true of bike lanes; they're considered roadways and bikes are considered vehicles.

Comment: @CareyGregory Actually, in many places and circumstances, pedestrians are allowed to walk on the surface of the road, against traffic. For example, on suburban roads without a sidewalk, this is usually legal.

Comment: @JohnDoucette Yes, there are such places (the street I live on, for example), but NYC isn't one of them.

Comment: @CareyGregory - Which is my point.  You need to find out what the rules are in NYC.  Unless someone here happens to live there, we can't tell you the rules -- only the NYC authorities can.  (Or perhaps NYC maintains a web site where you can look this up.)

Comment: Jaywalking is ticketable in NYC. Whether walking in the roadlane is included in jaywalking legally is something I'm not sure of.

Comment: @DVK - The general rules, applicable across most of the country (and of course generally ignored in many areas), allow walking at the edge of the roadway, facing traffic, and limit crossing the road on foot to intersections.  Of course, lots of individual variations, both state to state and city to city.  So again, the only way to know the answer is to specifically check the NYC rules.